# PyTorch specify model parameters

Tags: model, pytorch

I am trying to create a convolutional model in PyTorch where

- **one layer is fixed** (initialized to prescribed values)
- **another layer is learned** (but initial guess taken from prescribed values).

Here is a sample code for model definition:

```
import torch.nn as nn

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, weights_fixed, weights_guess):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.convL1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 3, 3, bias=False)
        self.convL1.weight = weights_fixed # I want to keep these weights fixed

        self.convL2 = nn.Conv1d(3, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.convL1.weight = weights_guess # I want to learn these weights

    def forward(self, inp_batch):
        out1 = self.convL1(inp_batch)
        out2 = self.convL2(out1)

        return out2
```

and the sample use:

```
weights_fixed = ...
weights_guess = ...

model = Net(weights_fixed, weights_guess)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optim = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)

train_dataset = ... #define training set here

for (X, y) in train_dataset:
    optim.zero_grad()
    out = model(X)
    loss = loss_fn(out, y)
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

**How can I make the weights 
weights_fixed - fixed and 
weights_guess - learnable?**

My guess would be 
    weights_fixed = nn.Parameter(W1,requires_grad=False)
    weights_guess = nn.Parameter(W2,requires_grad=True)
where for the sake of completeness
    import numpy as np
    import torch

```
krnl = np.zeros((5,order+1))
krnl[:,0] = [ 0. , 1., 0. ]
krnl[:,1] = [-0.5, 0., 0.5]
krnl[:,2] = [ 1. ,-2., 1. ]
W1 = torch.tensor(krnl)

a = np.array((1.,2.,3.))
W2 = torch.tensor(a)
```

But I am utterly confused. Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated. Of course I went over PyTorch docs, but it did not add clarity to my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the learnable parameter with `nn.Parameter` (`requires_grad=True` is the default, no need to specify this), and have the fixed weight as a Tensor without `nn.Parameter` wrapper.

All `nn.Parameter` weights are automatically added to `net.parameters()`, so when you do training like `optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)`, the fixed weight will not be changed.

So basically this:

```
weights_fixed = W1
weights_guess = nn.Parameter(W2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to optimizer only parameters that you want to learn:

```
optim = torch.optim.SGD(model.convL2.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)
# Now optimizer bypass parameters from convL1
```

If you model have more  layers, you must convert parameters to list:

```
params_to_update = list(model.convL2.parameters()) + list(model.convL3.parameters())
optim = torch.optim.SGD(params_to_update, lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)
```

as described here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/giving-multiple-parameters-in-optimizer/869

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
# this will be inside your class mostly
self.conv1.weight.requires_grad = False
```

And this will be where you are defining the optimizer :

`optimizer = optim.SGD(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, net.parameters()), lr=0.1)`

So, the optimizer will only use the parameters which have gradients enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your model definition to be:

```
import torch.nn as nn

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, weights_fixed, weights_guess):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.convL1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 3, 3, bias=False)
        self.convL1.weight = weights_fixed # I want to keep these weights fixed
        self.convL1.requires_grad = False

        self.convL2 = nn.Conv1d(3, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.convL1.weight = weights_guess # I want to learn these weights

    def forward(self, inp_batch):
        out1 = self.convL1(inp_batch)
        out2 = self.convL2(out1)

        return out2
```